# Linking image to marker on google maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

I have a custom marker on my map, and an image above the maps, which I would like to have on click, center the google map on the custom marker, the image is linked to. How would I do that with google api? I am terrible with figuring out what google api code could do this, could someone show me an example?

I am trying to add it to the companyimage variable

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head>
<LINK REL=StyleSheet HREF="styles.css" TYPE="text/css" MEDIA=screen>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<style type="text/css">
 html { height: 100% }
 body { height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px }
 #map_canvas { height: 100% }
</style>
  <script type="text/javascript"
      src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {
      var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(39.346246,-76.624446);
   var myOptions = {
     zoom: 15,
     center: latlng,
     mapTypeControl: true,
     mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
     navigationControl: true,
     navigationControlOptions: {style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL},
     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP};
   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
       myOptions);
       var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
                '<div id="siteNotice">'+
                '</div>'+
                '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Høgenhaug</h1>'+
                '<div id="bodyContent">'+
                '<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>'+
                      '</div>'+
                   '</div>';
                  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: contentString
               });

     var companyImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage('images/Loyola.png',
                    new google.maps.Size(100,50),
                    new google.maps.Point(0,0),
                   new google.maps.Point(50,50)
                  );

               var companyShadow = new    google.maps.MarkerImage('images/logo_shadow.png',
                   new google.maps.Size(130,50),
                   new google.maps.Point(0,0),
                   new google.maps.Point(65, 50));

                  var companyPos = new google.maps.LatLng(39.346246,-76.624446);

                  var companyMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: companyPos,
                map: map,
                icon: companyImage,
                shadow: companyShadow,
                title:"School",
                zIndex: 3});

                var trainImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage('images/barlandmark.png',
                new google.maps.Size(70,70),
                new google.maps.Point(0,0),
                new google.maps.Point(50,50)
            );

            var trainShadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage('images/train_shadow.png',
                new google.maps.Size(70,50),
                new google.maps.Point(0,0),
                new google.maps.Point(60, 50)
            );

               var trainPos = new google.maps.LatLng(39.363136,-76.609841);

               var trainMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: trainPos,
                map: map,
                icon: trainImage,
                shadow: trainShadow,
                title:"Train Station",
                zIndex: 2
            });
```

}

Comment: what version of the API are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with jquery and google API V-3 you can use

```
$("#yourImage").click(function(e){
    YOURMAP.setCenter(mapLat,mapLng); // add real lng and lat 
});
```

point the var YOURMAP to the map and the lat and lng an it will center on the point and resize if needed.

Comment: how do I point YOURMAP to the map? I'm sorry, I'm not great with javascript

Comment: by using a variable to encase the API functions to avoid conflicts http://www.sitepoint.com/google-maps-api-jquery/

Comment: So I should enclose the code that you posted in a variable, or within the variable that pertains to the marker?

Comment: As long as you set variable (`mapLat, mapLng`) as global you can use this anywhere. the `YOURMAP` in this case is the variable that houses the map js

Comment: Alright I did that. I have YOURMAP as map_canvas, which is my map id, and then use a div id called img in the body which has the picture of the image, but the image is still not clickable. I have the jquery in its own <script> tags in the head, and then the <div> tag with the image in the body

Comment: `
    $("#yourImage").click(function(e){
        google.maps.event.addListener(MYMAP.map, "click", function(event) {
            mapLat = event.latLng.lat();
            mapLng = event.latLng.lng();
            MYMAP.map.setCenter(mapLat,mapLng);
            google.maps.event.clearListeners(MYMAP.map, 'click');
        });
    });`  you may not be updating you Lat and Lng try this

Comment: Alright I will put that in. Can you check the source code of my page that I posted in another comment and see if i'm doing it the right way?

Comment: try this `
    $("#lookHere").click(function(e){
            MYMAP.map.setCenter(39.363136,-76.609841);
    });`

Comment: Still no click option for the image. You can check out http://campustaps.com/googlemaps.html. I don't know why the click(function(e) isn't working

Comment: you have an error in your js "companyMarker is not defined" is the profile output, I would check scope first. then look for miss spelled viriables.

Comment: your jquery is never called `$("#img").click(function(e){ map_canvas.map.setCenter(39.363136,-76.609841);` this handler is never set with the ready() function, here is a link, http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery that is likey why the other function I send did not work.

Comment: I'm sorry not that great with Jquery. I will look into the page you linked and try to understand how to use the code you wrote, but if I write it correctly, it should work?

Comment: the code I send is the code I'm using on one of my maps, after it's in the `ready()` function the `setCenter(39.363136,-76.609841)` id a part of the google map API. it take the map variable and will center on the lat and lng (most of the time a variable) http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html there is a lot of but the `setCenter()` method maybe what you want.

Answer (score 0):

http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Map

```
yourMap.panTo( yourMarker.getPosition() );
```

Answer (score 0):

Youd need to do something like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#img").live('click',function(){
        var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
        map.setCenter(pos);
    });
});
</script>
```

Or

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#img").live('click',function(){
        var pos = marker.getPosition();
        map.setCenter(pos);
    });
});
</script>
```

And make sure you change the id of your image to match the selector.

```
<img src='someimage.jpg' id ='img' />
```

Make sure you replace map with the name of your created map.
Replace marker with the name of your created marker.
And if using the first example, replace lat/lng with the correct positions.

Google Maps Events for API V3

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/events.html

Comment: great thanks. And now should this be placed in its own variable? or within the variable of my custom marker?

Comment: This code should be included with the rest of your javascript. Check the edit for better usage.

Comment: I did and put map_canvas in for the 'map.setcenter' part like you said, but there is no click for the picture.

Comment: Make sure you change $("#img") to the name of your image.. eg:

<img src='test.jpg id='my_image'/>

Comment: I did, could the issue be the fact that I have the image in the body of the document as well? I should just have one instance of it?

Comment: If your using ID's instead of class's you must only have one instance of that ID.. And yes the image should be in the body of the page.

Comment: here is what I have. http://campustaps.com/googlemaps.html I can't seem to get the image to have a click ability

Comment: Still not working. Sorry about causing problems. Two questions, 1.$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#img").live('click',function(){
        var pos = marker.getPosition();
        map.setCenter(pos);
    });
});
 needs to be within the companyImage var since that is the marker it is centering on?